# TileList item location

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

In a flex tileList, is there a way to get the cell-address of a given item? i.e. for a given item, get the row/column location for that item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the documentation, and no directly, but with a bit of arithmetic you can get yourself sorted.

```
//asumming this is a change handler
function myTileListChanged(event:Event):void{
    var itemsPerRow:Number = myTileList.dataProvider.length / myTileList.rowCount;
    var selectedRow:int = Math.floor(myTileList.selectedIndex / itemsPerRow);
    var selectedColumn:int = myTileList.selectedIndex - (itemsPerRow * selectedRow);
    trace('index: ' + myTileList.selectedIndex + ' is at row: ' + selectedRow + ' column: ' + selectedColumn);
}
```

Note, I've used the TileList in Flash, so dataProvider might be slightly different, but you'll
still be able to get the picture.
HTH!